# Convert json array value to integer

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am querying and returning a numeric column from a MySQL table to a json array. However, when I try to access the last element in the array, it returns it as a string. I tried casting it with an int, but then it returns a 0. Here is my code:

```
public function get_latest_subcategory_id() {

    $ids = $this->query("SELECT SubCategory_ID FROM SubCategory");
    if ($ids->num_rows > 0) {

        $arr_json = array();
        while ($row = $ids->fetch_row()) {
            $json = json_encode($row);
            $arr_json[] = $json;
        }
        echo $arr_json[$ids->num_rows-1];
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Is there a way I can retrieve it as an integer?

Comment: echo intval($array_json[$ids->num_rows-1],10) ?

Comment: Still returns a 0...

Comment: What is your final goal? You are encoding each query row before adding it to array. I think you have instead to create a standard array and to encode it at the end.

Comment: i just want to be able to get the entire numeric column (consists of IDs) from my table, and grab the last element (the most recent ID).

Comment: You are making an array of JSON objects though. If all you need is the the last ID then why does JSON need to be involved at all?

Comment: sorry, im new to php/mysql. maybe it doesnt, but i was trying to work off an example i found onine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON doesn't really do anything here. It's also really inefficient to go through the entire database just to get the last row. Why not do something like this?

```
public function get_latest_subcategory_id() {
    $ids = $this->query("SELECT SubCategory_ID FROM SubCategory ORDER BY SubCategory_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
    if ($ids->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $ids->fetch_row();
        return intval($row[0]);
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Does this method not go through the entire database?

Comment: @DeeTee No, `ORDER BY SubCategory_ID DESC` tells MySQL to return the highest SubCategory_ID first and `LIMIT 1` tells MySQL to only return the first result.